# Intercept PDF Form Submission with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, submit

I have an embedded PDF Form which is not a regular form. Nonetheless, there is a Submit button in the PDF which submits a regular HTTP GET query to a specified URL.

Is there any way for me to intercept the submittal of the form in JavaScript? I need to have custom behavior on the Submit action. Thanks

Comment: I believe the changes would have to be embedded in the document itself. What tools do you have available for editing PDF documents?  What is it that you want to do when the form submits? Are you completely tied to javascript? What if I have another solution that is not js?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a little digging in the PDF spec, and actually modify the document itself.  This will not be easy if you don't have tools that allow you to do this already, and probably won't be possible if your pdf is encrypted unless you have the proper keys.  If you are trying to figure out how to do this using Acrobat or some other such tool then you are probably asking in the wrong place.

The section of the [PDF Specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf) that you want is 8.6.4 (Form Actions) and the section on Javascript actions begins on page 556.

If all you are interested in is form validation then there are easier options built into PDF already...

Comment: Thanks for the reference into the PDF spec. Saved me loads of time searching for it.

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to intercept a form's submission event with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myForm").submit(function() {

        //DO SOMETHING

    });

});
```

*"#myForm" is the proper css-style selector given your form element's id attribute

Here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

You must include the jQuery library in your page. [More on jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#jQuery%3a_The_Basics)

Comment: No page, no html, no jquery... He is talking about a form embedded into a pdf document.